# How to fill textbox on check box check changed using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am doing a web application where I am entering the program details based on orgainization.
For that the user selects the orgainization first`(from  dropdown which is taken from database on pageload)`,then there is a provision for entering the program address details.The address can be same as organization address.So i put a checkbox like this

```
Enter the program address: [checkbox] Same as organization adress
```

If the user ticks the checkbox, i want to fill the program address details same as that of organization address.

I know i can do this on `checkbox checkchanged event`.But i dont want to do it on this method as there will be postback and i am not using any update panel.

Is there any method to achieve the above using jquery ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a breeze with JQuery. I like to disable the copied fields after so the user knows to modify the source. I put a sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baUTZ/) up for you and have some sample JQuery below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#idofcheckbox').click(function () {
        $('#idofothertext').val($('#idoftextbox').val());
        $('#idofothertext').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```

Based on your comment above you will need to build a webservice to expose this database field and call it via ajax in jquery. [This](http://chandradev819.wordpress.com/2011/04/08/how-to-populate-dropdown-on-client-side-using-web-service-and-jquery/) is a good read on building a webservice and then consuming it with AJAX. You could then extend the code above to handle the Ajax call on click and it will not post back.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#idofcheckbox').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "test.html",
                context: document.body
            }).done(function (data) {
                $('#idofothertext').val(data.address);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Here we have to pass the `organization id` to the webservice.How can we do that ?

Comment: You can either do that with a url param on the url of the webservice or in the data setting. Look at data in the jquery docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

use on change like this  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KuTe9/1)

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
```

jquery

```
$('#chk1').on('change',function(){
if(this.checked)
    $('#txt2').val($('#txt1').val());
else
    $('#txt2').val('');
});
```

Comment: Here the problem is  the  organization name and organization id are the two fields taken from the db.Now i will take organization address also.But how will we able to fill the textbox with address taken from the db.?Hope you understand the scenario..